# How to store tokens from a text file in java

Tags: java, text-files, token

I figured it out. I had the counter's as integers instead of doubles.

```
public class Family

{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
        String token = "";
        File fileName = new File("MaleFemaleInFamily.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        double counterGG = 0;
        double counterBG = 0;
        double counterBB = 0;
        double totalCounter = 0;
        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
            token = inFile.next();
            System.out.println(token);
            if (token.equals("GG")) {
                counterGG++;
                totalCounter++;
            } else if (token.equals("BG")) {
                counterBG++;
                totalCounter++;
            } else if (token.equals("GB")) {
                counterBG++;
                totalCounter++;
            } else if (token.equals("BB")) {
                counterBB++;
                totalCounter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Sample Size: " + totalCounter);
        System.out.println("Two Boys: " + (counterBB / totalCounter) + "%");
        System.out.println("One Boy One Girl: " + (counterBG / totalCounter) + "%");
        System.out.println("Two Girls: " + (counterGG / totalCounter) + "%");
        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

I got everything to counter correctly, but when I do the math of `(counterGG / totalCounter)` and `(counterBG / totalCounter)` and `(counterBB / totalCounter)` it just comes out to zero. What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: What is the format of your file? Does it have only one of those tokens in each line?

Comment: You might want to look in the `String.split` method. `String.split(" ")` in particular if you have more than one a line.

Comment: Yes, it only has two characters on each line.

Comment: @user1745508 counter=3 after executing your code. it seems correct. what is your problem actually?

Comment: Try printing out the value of `counter`.

Comment: Oh my...I didn't even think to output my counter. Gosh, i've been learning too long today.

Comment: When asking a question like this it is ***imperative*** that you include in your post the actual output from your program.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasNextLine` and `nextLine` methods instead. Since every entry is in a separate line it more sense, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (prints 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File fileName = new File("test2.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
    int counter = 0;

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        String token = inFile.next();
        System.out.println(token);
        if (token.equals("GG")) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```